# Error while reading a .csv file and send it into google spreadsheet using kodular

Tags: json, google-sheets, app-inventor

I want to read a csv file and send the data to a google spreadsheet. I am following the given link
https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/export-csv-data-multiple-data-to-google-sheet

But I am getting the error as shown in the image.
[image: Error]

My app script code is as follows

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents) ; // or >> eval(e.postData.contents) ;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    sh.appendRow(data[i]);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success") ;
}
```

My kodular blocks are shown in the image
[image: Kodular blocks]

Comment: your question already has been answered here https://community.kodular.io/t/i-want-to-send-a-list-of-numbers-from-kodular-app-to-google-spreadsheet/150808?u=taifun

Answer (score 0):

The line with *JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)* on google script got incorrect text to parse it.
In kodular, the list "global data" is something like ((11,12),(21,22)...).
To be valid JSON it has be like {[[11,12],[21,22]...]}.
So, you should replace all round brackets () with square brackets [], and add curly brackets to start and end.
Change 'global data' before you call 'Web1.Post Text' as shown:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCXV5.png